# Change the color of edittextview when enter the data

Tags: android-edittext

I have three edittexts,when i enter the digit the edittext view color should change and cursor should go to another edittext,only color should appear and data should not appear.when delete the data in edittext color should delete

Comment: Show code You have, with comments what logic is expected

Comment: when value entered in to editext,value should be hide and view should turn to blue and when deleted the valuve the view should be again came back to previous color @JacekCz